# How do I resample an array of signal data that will not fit in memory in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory

I have an array of accelerometer data of size 200,000,000x3 that I need to resample in matlab.
After calling the resample function with this data, I receive an "out of memory" error. (my computer has 8 GB of RAM)

What I tried:
I loaded my accelerometer data (x,y,z) as one array and time data as another array. I created a tall array for each, then tried calling the resample function again.

the error I received this time said: "First argument must be a tall column vector."

Please help me understand the proper way to accomlish this task. Thank you!

Comment: You're not running a 32-bit operating system, are you?

Comment: “After calling the resample function with this data” How did you call it? It matters a lot what you tried. Please post code!

Comment: Split the raw data into 1000 chunks and save the intermediate data as files, then repeat resampling 1000 times?

Comment: @wwweagle Yes! that is the solution I have implemented and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab by default puts everything in a 64 bit number.  If your acc data is limited to 8 or 16 or 32 bit values, you can save some space by using those number types.  However, this can be problematic depending on what you want to do, as not all functions in matlab can use non-64 bit numbers.

Arrays need a contiguous chunk of memory, so a 3xn array will need 3*n*8 bytes of memory + a little more for overhead.  I think that if you do 3 1xn arrays, you may consume more memory, but it doesn't have to be in one chunk.

You can try closing down everything so that you machine has large chunks of memory available, too.

Depending on the data, I would probably write a quick awk script to pull out every nth point and put that in a smaller file that could be read before I even put the data into matlab.

It sounds like you can load the data, but what is your resample function?  Are you reducing the data or trying to interpolate it to a finer time vector?

You could load your data, delete part of it, save that to a mat file, and repeat.  Then operate on you various mat files.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I ended up finding a workaround where I read chunks of the original file at a time. I was using the built-in MATLAB function resample. The data is actually from a .cwa file which includes a 3-axis accelerometer, light, and temp data. I was reducing the accelerometer data and interpolating the temp and light data.